# Make a queue of events RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I would like to know if it is possible make a queue (with identifier for example, like "Q") with RxSwift like:

> On ViewController1 I **send** an event1 to queue Q.
>
> On ViewController2 I **send** other event2 to Q.
>
> On ViewController3 I **handle** the events 1 and 2 of the queue, with identifier Q.

**EDIT, specifing the problem:**

I have to present multiple ViewControllers as modal. So for example ViewController1 says that needs to show a popup on ViewController2, but ViewController2 have to show another popup too, so I need a queue there in order to not present all popups at the same time, so one after the other.

I am new on Rx so I am not sure if this is possible. Also if there is a way to do it without RxSwift I am open to try it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please specify more the question, I don't fully understand it... But if I get you correctly, you probably need to observe some FlowCoordinator pattern behaviour instead of ViewControllers itself...

Comment: I specified a bit, I hope is enough, I am going to check FlowCoordinator pattern, tho. @DominikBucher